# How to use drag and drop in displayfield in extjs?

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop

I need to include drag and drop to change order of rows in displayfield. Although I have tried a lot of ways, I could not do it.

This is the picture of my form.
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0aa3nt0mf5

Comment: Post at least three ways you tried...

Comment: First, I try to use gridpanel to use gridviewdragdrop. Then I use draggable of properties of displayfield. Finally, I use onDrag's event.